# leak in rear-left of 1998 Honda CRV

Tags: honda, fuel-system, leak

I have a Honda CRV which is parked on a very very slight hill, nose up. There is a small puddle just inside of the rear-left wheel that smells like gasoline. When I crawl up under I can see some slightly damp parts, but no origin for the leak.

The car had the gas tank filled earlier today.

I don't think the incline is enough to bring a leak from the front all the way to the rear, or even a few feet down the chassis before dripping.

Any ideas where the leak would be coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gas tanks are usually in the rear, and when you fill them to the brim they can leak out of the:

- Evaporation system ports
- Fuel fill hose joints
- Out of the gas cap if it expands enough
- The tank itself

What side is your fuel door on?

Comment: I did not fill the tank but I was assured it was not filled to the brim. The leak is on the same side as the fuel door.

Comment: Gas will expand quite a bit on a hot day.I would check the joint between the fill tube and evap hose at the tank that run up to the fill port.

Comment: That was it. Filled in the morning, hot day hits while car is parked in driveway with full gas tank. Haven't seen any leakage since, will keep an eye on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Check the condition of the filler pipe. I had a '93 Volkswagen Polo on which that pipe rusted through, leading to the same symptoms you mention - it ran behind the wing in such a way that the gap filled with mud and trapped moisture against the pipe, causing it to corrode prematurely. A lot of cars also incorporate a rubber hose as part of either filler or evaporation pipes, which can perish and leak - a slight leak from a perishing hose can be very difficult to locate as there is often no visible hole.

As the fuel evaporates, you may well find it will leave a white crystalline deposit behind, which may help with locating the source of the leak.

Answer (score 2):

Check your Filler tube, where they run against the frame of the car...I have a 98 CRV, and the Fuel Filler Tubes rusted right at the point where they are mounted to the frame...The vent tube (smaller tube) corroded to the point that gas was seeping out and leaving a puddle on the ground. Problem at this point is, they are slightly level with the inlets to the gas tank, so when parked of a level surface, gas will leak out..Replacement of the Fuel Filler Tube and the rubber hoses connecting them to the gas tank, should take care of this problem...Hope this was helpful